# Regex while-loop only pushes 1 value to my array

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

My variable `htmlContent` contains a string with content in properly formatted HTML code, it contains multiple `img` tags.

I'm trying to get all the values of the images `src` attribute and put them in an array `srcList`.

However, the problem I'm facing with the following code is that it always alerts an array with only 1 source value in it, while I have it set up to push *all* the source URLs to the array and not just one.

```
let srcList = [],
    imgSrc,
    regex = /<img.*src="(.*?)"/gi;

while ((imgSrc = regex.exec(htmlContent)) !== null) {
    srcList.push(imgSrc[1]);
}

alert(JSON.stringify(srcList));
```

How can I make this work as I expect it to?

Comment: Have you used `str.match(regexp)`? It will return an array containing the entire match result and any parentheses-captured matched results; null if there were no matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.*` between `img` and `src` in your regex is greedily matching everything from the first `img` to the last `src` -- your code is otherwise essentially correct, but will only catch the last image source for that reason.

Example with that greedy match replaced with something that will only match within each `<img>` tag (if, as noted in comments, the html string is a single line):

```js
let srcList = [],
  imgSrc,
  regex = /<img[^>]*src="(.*?)"/gi;

let htmlContent = '<img src="foo"><img class="bat" src="bar"><img src="baz">';


while (imgSrc = regex.exec(htmlContent)) {
  srcList.push(imgSrc[1]);
}

console.log(srcList);
```

(I feel compelled to insert the obligatory "[don't try to parse HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)" warning here.  Consider something like `$('img').each(function() {srcList.push($(this).attr('src'))}` instead.)

Comment: Right only if document source code is within a whole line.

Comment: True that.  All the more reason to not use regex when parsing html.

Comment: There is no problem using regular expressions here. All that elements and attributes, I don't call it HTML parsing.

Comment: Well, it's HTML, and we're parsing it, so...  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  YMMV but pretty much every time I've thought to myself "oh, this is just a simple match, I can use a regex" I've wound up regretting it.  For one-off throwaway code, sure, fine; for anything that I'm going to have to maintain it's usually better to do it the right way in the first place.

Comment: You see it HTML, I see it a raw text. Regular expressions are not that regular any more so as a powerful text-processing tool, in such cases, there wouldn't be any problem if you know what you are going to do, indeed.

Comment: Well, hey, I don't agree; but to each his own, you do you, different strokes, etc

Comment: Sure but then you wouldn't disagree.